# Error with timezone in @DateTimeFormat

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring's `@DateTimeFormat` annotation in order to parse the output of `toISOString()` from javascript:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<Entity> search(@RequestParam("date") @DateTimeFormat(pattern="\"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ\"") Date date) {
    return service.search(date);
}
```

The URL ends up looking like: `?date="2014-07-14T19:19:33.625Z"` which seems correct.  `@DateTimeFormat` is not correctly parsing the timezone, it seems like it wants UTC to be represented as '-0000' instead of 'Z'

Am I doing something wrong? You would expect `@DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.DATE_TIME)` to work with javascript `toISOString()`, except js is adding the quotes and 'Z' doesn't seem to work.

This is Spring 3.1.